# What is the main difference between ER and EER diagrams?

Tags: database, database-design, entity, entity-relationship, diagram

I would like to understand what is the main difference between ER and EER diagrams. I know that EER should include subclasses/superclasses, specialisation/generalisation, categories, attributes, and relationship inheritance. However, when it comes to diagrams I am not sure how to proceed from ER diagrams to make them EER.

I made up the following diagram - football match. How would I develop it into EER diagram?

[image: Football match]

Answer (score 0):

The EERD notation (enhanced ERD) is an extension of the ERD notation.  So if you have an ERD diagram and if you don't need any of the EERD features, you can consider that it is already an EERD diagram.

This being said, there is not one EERD notation but several. It all starts with  two main families of non-extended ERD diagrams, that bot provide very well for attributes:

- The Chen notation with the diamonds for relationships: it allows to represent all the concepts of the Entity-Relationship theory, that was invented by ... Mr. Chen
- The Crow's foot notation that was invented before Entity-Relationship theory, and cannot express some advanced ERD features like an associative entity, and needs already some notational extensions/ehan ements/variants to express basic ERD features, like a weak or strong entity and relationship.

The two mostly used EERD notations build on top of Chen notation and differ in how they note the inheritance:

- One notation uses triangles for generalization/specialization for `IsA` (see for example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Subclasses-Superclasses-and-Inheritance))
- The other  uses circles for generalization/specialization and unions (see for example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enhanced-er-model/amp/)).

None of the two are standardized. They appear in some academic papers but didn't make it to standardization bodies.

***P.S**: A more harmonized notation is UML class diagrams, which allows to represent most ERD concepts out of the box, with a streamlined notation, and covers also the concepts introduced by EERDs with the benefit that there is one authoritative standard.*